# getActivity() overhead

Tags: android, performance, software-design

Purely from a Software Engineering perspective, how much overhead does `getActivity()` have?

I am constantly using this method multiple times throughout my application and considering having a global variable with reference to `getActivity()` instead.

What would other complications be by having a global variable for `Activity` involve?

My app has only one `activity` but many fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store your `Actvivity` in a global variable you might risk a memory leak (especially if you store it in external classes / `Fragment`), as I suppose you'll be saving it in a traditional way in a `strong` reference. E.g:

```
public MyActivity myActivity = getActivity();
```

Although there hasn't been a final global agreement on this, the most likely outcome is that when `Android` tries to `gc` the `Activity`, it will be blocked as there are still `strong` references pointing to it.

A possible solution would be wrap your `Activity` in either a `java.lang.ref.SoftReference<T>` or a `java.lang.ref.WeakReference<T>`.

E.g:

```
private Reference<MyActivity> activityReference = new WeakReference<>(myActivity);
```

and when you retrieve it ( in external classes / `Fragment`s ) check if hasn't been `gc`'d yet:

```
if (activityReference.get() != null) {
    // still alive...
}
```

and yes, people do that.

---

As @Sarthak Mittal says, do not try to optimize as long as you do not notice a particular overhead in your application.

Also, check the code for `getActivity()` as it may simply be a `getter`, in which case it shouldn't carry any significant computational expense.

Comment: there are a few things that I would like to mention:
1) The scenario you talk about is quite different, the OP is inside a fragment and wants to know the impact of calling `getActivity()` frequently.
2) I don't think that we should use SoftReference to hold views/activity(though it will also prevent a memory leak) because as soon as all strong references run out of scope, we shouldn't be needing that view/activity anymore. :)

Comment: @SarthakMittal He did mention considering storing the result of `getActivity()` in a variable, and you never really know how that can affect the application. My answer is indeed suitable for that particular scenario, not the effect of calling `getActivity()` frequently. My proposed way is one way to do it. Still, the issue here is, as you say, premature optimization.

Comment: somehow skipped that part sorry :)

Comment: @SarthakMittal no probs

Answer (score 2):

**You are really worrying about premature optimization.**

In modern systems, the time taken to call a method which simply returns an instance variable is in nanoseconds(maybe not in the case of android devices, but still, it isn't something to worry about at all)